# Is it possible to automatically "flex-shrink" only elements with large content?

Tags: css, flexbox

In a container with property `display: flex;` and a fixed size, is it possible to only shrink child elements which would take more than the space available if we evenly distributed it? It would be trivial knowing the content sizes beforehand but I'm looking for a solution which works for dynamic content without resorting to Javascript.

Here's an example:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
}
.item {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

/* Making it prettier -- unrelated to the question */
.container {
  background-color: #cde;
  padding: 5px;
}
.item {
  margin: 0;
}
.item:not(:last-of-type) {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.item:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #dec;
}
.item:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #ced;
}
.item:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #dce;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="item">sm</p>
  <p class="item">paragraph with large content</p>
  <p class="item">another large content</p>
</div>
```

We can see that for the first item the letter `m` has been partly cut out (it shrunk). Given that this item is small enough (I'll properly define this below) I would want to prevent it from shrinking, like this:

[image: comparison between default render and intended goal]

The logic I'm aiming for is this: if we distribute the container width evenly between `n` child elements each one would have `childWidth = parentWidth/n`; then those that have width (based on its content) less than or equal to this value don't shrink while the other ones do shrink if necessary (it may be the case that the available space allows for all items to be fully displayed).

Is this possible with CSS only?

Comment: have you tried `min-width: min-content`, to specify the minimum width is the content's minimum width

Comment: @cursorsdottsx it doesn't work because we need to be able to prevent the shrinkage for *any* small item (content is dynamic for all of them).

Comment: :v hm well then... if it's dynamic then why don't you use javascript to do it, i cant think of any pure css way to do this if the content is dynamic

Comment: Yes, I can do it with JS, I'm only searching for a pure css way because if it exists it's much more elegant IMO and lightweight. If it doesn't then ok, I'll go with the JS solution.

Comment: actually, there is a nice way to do it, but it involves a little JS still;
use css to do the styling based on an attribute on the element, and use JS to set the attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr()

Comment: The styling would be `flex-shrink: 0` or `flex-shrink: 1` and the decision of which one to apply depends on the width after the element is rendered, so I would have to use something like this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect wouldn't I? I think this is too much. Do you see a simpler way? I don't like approximating the width based on the content length/chars because it changes if we change the font being used for example.

Comment: Is `n` fixed? Or is it also dynamic?

Comment: Dynamic but "not that much": `1 <= n <= 4`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have tested out my comment and it works! Hurray!

This works because it sets the minimum width of the element to the minimum width that can fit the content.

I have set it for only the first item, like you wanted:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
}
.item {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

/* Making it prettier -- unrelated to the question */
.container {
  background-color: #cde;
  padding: 5px;
}
.item {
  margin: 0;
}
.item:not(:last-of-type) {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.item:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #dec;
  min-width: min-content;
}
.item:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #ced;
}
.item:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #dce;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="item">sm</p>
  <p class="item">paragraph with large content</p>
  <p class="item">another large content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: If we know which elements are small then it works indeed, the problem is that every item has dynamic content. So if we add `min-width: min-content` to the class `.item` it doesn't work :/ but thanks for the suggestion!